# Http get Request not returning the file but information about it

Tags: angular, typescript, http, request

I need to retrieve the content of a file from an (VSTS) API. The file is in a git repository.

However, when I request the file, I receive information about the file but not the content :

```
commitId: "024576d864ea12413fa9b**77aa11dde4292f62a"
gitObjectType: "blob"
objectId: "ad9b48a957db402**705cc2924b46f4573178f13"
path: "/file.json"
size : 6879
url: "https://****.visualstudio.com/d98**9e7-f21c-5bf7-8c3b-cdefde559700/_apis/git/repositories/83abc*bd-9ee5-44d2-9***-abcbebbcff29/items?path=%2Ffile.json&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
_links: {self: {…}, repository: {…}, blob: {…}}
```

Here is my code :

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa('user:password')
  })
};

public getFile(): any {
    this.HttpClient.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

The exact same request with Postman (same Url and Headers) gets me the content of the file. Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong in my code ?

Comment: Do you want to download the file?

Comment: I just wanted to get the content of the file as a response, but at this point even downloading it is a nice step forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a method to download the file explicitly:

```
private downloadFile(data) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data._links.blob);
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.download = 'your-file-name.txt';
    anchor.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
}
```

now call this on subscription of your GET call:

```
this.HttpClient.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
  this.downloadFile(data);
});
```

Comment: Just tried this, it downloads a file with the exact same information in it that I get when requesting the file and logging the response. The information is correct btw, it's just not what I want. Sorry, I know this is a strange one.

Comment: Hmm, I see that there is a `blob` key in your response. Can you try passing that to the `downloadFile()`? Something like : `this.downloadFile(data._links.blob)`

Comment: I made it work in the end, your answer gave me an idea : Doing a second request using the Blob's Url : It returns the data I desperately needed. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Oh that's great. Glad to help!